# Batch file not getting directory name until second run

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script for the purpose of setting up a dev environment for a Django instance. Part of this is setting the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable. If no arguments are supplied the script runs this block of code:

```sh
for %%* in (.) do set DIR=%%~n*
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%DIR%.dev_settings
```

When the script is first called it sets `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to only `.dev_settings`. When I run the script a second time in the same terminal it sets it correctly from the directory name.

I have no idea why this is the case.

Below is the full script in case you need full context.

```sh
@echo off
IF "%1"=="-r" (
    set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="
) ELSE IF "%1"=="" (
    start cmd /c prp-sql
    for %%* in (.) do set DIR=%%~n*
    set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%DIR%.dev_settings
) ELSE IF "%2"=="" (
    start cmd /c prp-sql
    set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%1.dev_settings
) ELSE (
    start cmd /c prp-sql
    set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%1.%2
)
```

Comment: When you set a variable inside a parenthesis `()` block you will need to call it in order to see the results or have used `enabledelayedexpansion` on a `setlocal` command and used `!` instead of `%` to expand thw variable.  I will post the amended code as the answer

Comment: Classic [delayed expansion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028). But you don't necessarily need delayed expansion. Just do `for %%* in (.) do set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%%~n*.dev_settings"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a variable inside a parenthesis `()` block you will need to call it in order to see the results or have used `enabledelayedexpansion` on a `setlocal` command and used `!` instead of `%` to expand thw variable.

Below is the amended code

```
@(
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
   echo off
)

IF /I "%1"  EQU "-r" (
    set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="
   Goto :EOF
) 
start cmd /c prp-sql
IF /I "%2" NEQ "" (
  set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%1.%2"
) ELSE (
  IF /I "%1" NEQ "" (
    set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%1.dev_settings"
  ) ELSE (
    for %%_ in (.) do set "DIR=%%~n_"
    set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=!DIR!.dev_settings"
  )
)
```

Alternatively if you don't need to re-use DIR later you can just set the Django settings variable directly in the loop:

```
for %%_ in (.) do (
    set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%%~n_.dev_settings"
  )
```

Below is that version of the amended code

```
@(
  SETLOCAL
   echo off
)

IF /I "%1"  EQU "-r" (
    set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="
   Goto :EOF
) 
start cmd /c prp-sql
IF /I "%2" NEQ "" (
  set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%1.%2"
) ELSE (
  IF /I "%1" NEQ "" (
    set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%1.dev_settings"
  ) ELSE (
    for %%_ in (.) do set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%%~n_.dev_settings"
  )
)
```

### Notes

One final Q, are you sure you want to start `start cmd /c prp-sql` before setting django?

Whether before or after, put that part in only once after determining it should run (is not -r) and either before or after the if structure to set the Django variable.

I changed the script to just stop aftwr hitting -r since nother after would normally execute.

Comment: Thanks for your help; the if-else structure was just how it ended up after my frustration. Batch files have me feeling like a novice again haha.